# Order by clause oracle conditional

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

Hello I am trying to make an order by clause where the output must display ascending order of "Child Name", and if the child name is the same then order the output by child code.

```
ORDER by CASE
             WHEN "Child Name" = "Child Name" THEN
                 child_code
             ELSE
                 "child Name" asc
            end;
```

I get an error saying missing keyword but not sure

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want two keys in the `ORDER BY`:

```
order by "Child Name", child_code
```

Comment: Aside from overthinking it, you should reconsider your use of mixed-case table/column names in double-quotes.  That actually makes the case-_sensitive_, which just causes all kinds of difficulties.  Create your object names _without_ double-quotes and they will be case-_in_sensitive.  This is probably different from other db's you've worked with, like MSSQL.